X11 Pixels buffer drawing. Pixmap vs XImage
I'm learning the approaches to draw a buffer of pixels on window using X11 API. I found that Pixelmap and XImage both can be used for this purpose. What is the difference between Pixmap and XImage& What and when should I use for better performance?
